# Highstock different time value interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a WebService that return a list of Chart. This is the structure of my class diagram:

```
public class Point
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}

public class Serie
{
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public List<Point> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Chart
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public List<Serie> Series { get; set; }
}

public List<Chart> charts;
```

I use HighStock, in a js script to display all my charts from my list of chart.
I want group my series by unit and for each unit a create a new yAxis to display the same unit series (see the images below).

This is the code from the js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService.asmx/Channels",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Charts) {
                document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = Charts.d;
                Charts = Charts.d;

                var margin = 40,
                top = 100,
                height = 160,
                count = 0;

                // Generals options for chart
                var options = {
                    credits: { enabled: false },
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: chart,
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        alignTicks: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Values'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2,
                        shared: true
                    },
                    xAxis: {       
                        ordinal: false
                    },
                    yAxis: [],
                    series: []
                };

                // Go through Charts
                for (var i in Charts) {

                        // Infos for the yAxis of the serie
                        // -------------------
                        options.yAxis.push({
                            title: {
                                text: "[" + Charts[i].Unit + "]"
                            },
                            labels: {
                                x: 30,
                                y: 4,
                                align: "right",
                                format: '{value} ' + Charts[i].Unit
                            },
                            offset: 0,
                            top: top,
                            height: height,
                            opposite: true
                        });

                        // Go through Series in a Charts
                        for (var j in Charts[i].Series) {


                            // Infos for the serie
                            // -------------------
                            var data = [];

                            // Go through Data in Series of a Charts
                            for (var k in Charts[i].Series[j].Data) {
                                var point = new Array(new Date(Charts[i].Series[j].Data[k].Date).getTime(), Charts[i].Series[j].Data[k].Value);
                                data.push(point);
                            }// End: Go through Data in Series of a Charts

                            count = Number(i);

                            // Add a serie and these attributes
                            options.series.push({
                                name: Charts[i].Series[j].Name,
                                data: data,
                                tooltip: {
                                    valueSuffix: ' ' + Charts[i].Series[j].Unit,
                                    valueDecimals: 3
                                },
                                yAxis: count
                            });

                        }// End: Go through Series in a Charts

                        count++;
                        top += height + margin;

                }// End: Go through Charts

                options.chart.height = top + 190;

                Highcharts.StockChart(options);
            },
            error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
                //alert("Error : " + xhr.status + "\nMessage : \n" + xhr.responseText);
                document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "Error : " + xhr.status + "\nMessage : \n" + xhr.responseText;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I run the code:

[Blank page no chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7XVD.jpg)

The error that I have is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined -> highstock.js:177

and also (sometime) this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined -> highstock.js:342 (not sur about the #line)

If I remove the serie with the different interval or if a unselect the Vbatt serie (the serie with the different interval) it works:

[All my charts are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwXC8.jpg)

I spent a lot of time on internet and StackOverflow to find an issue for my problem but... nothing...

***Edit***:

-> What is the max serie that we can plot on the same chart?
-> What is the max point that we can plot on the same chart?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Best regards,

Steeve

**Problem solved!**

The problem was that the epoch data send by my webservice was in secondes and HighStock need to have millisecondes.

Comment: There is not such limitation like number of series or point (unless it won't be an overkill for a browser). Could you try master branch for Highstock? See http://github.highcharts.com/highstock.src.js - I think I've met similar issues. Also, any chance to recreate issue on jsfiddle? You can use static data, instead of AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

The problem was that the epoch data send by my webservice was in secondes and HighStock need to have millisecondes.